# How do I split a string in a pandas dataframe and convert the remaining to datetime format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a column in my pandas dataframe which has rows containing the below:

2021-01-04T23:00:00.000+00:00

I would like to split it and keep only the date element and convert the string to a date format:

04/01/2021

I have tried to use split string but I am unable to get to the final stage of then converting to a date format.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't, split. Convert [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and export to the desired format directly with [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

output:

```
                             col         new
0  2021-01-04T23:00:00.000+00:00  04/01/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the date using pd.datatime and then format the date

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```